# Ellipsis effect on MUI textfield

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, textfield, word-wrap

How do i add ellipsis effect on MUI textfield? They have a multi line option for text wrap, but I want a single line, wrapping the text like you can do with `<Text numberOfLines={1} ellipsizeMode='head'>long long long long text<Text>`.

ref: https://mui.com/material-ui/react-text-field/

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can specify the ellipsis for the input. Here is a working [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/modest-matsumoto-eorbsn?file=/demo.js:332-622)

```
    <TextField
        id="outlined-basic"
        label="Outlined"
        variant="outlined"
        sx={{
          "& .MuiInputBase-input": {
            overflow: "hidden",
            textOverflow: "ellipsis"
          }
        }}
        value="ver long text with ellipsis"
      />
```