# Text not aligning properly on MUI card component

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, frontend

I am new to react, I've been following a course and building a demo project. I've tried but for some reason i can't align the **price** text on a card that has a single line of description. In fact, I want the **price** to appear on the bottom left of the cards. This is what my code looks like. Any suggestion would be appreciated.

```
import Card from '@mui/material/Card';
import CardContent from '@mui/material/CardContent';
import CardMedia from '@mui/material/CardMedia';
import Typography from '@mui/material/Typography';

const ItemCard = (props) => {
  // return <div className={classes.card}>{props.children}</div>;

  return (
    <div>
      <Card
        sx={{
          maxWidth: 345,
          maxHeight: '100%',
          boxShadow: '0 2px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25)',
          height: '350px'
        }}
      >
        <CardMedia component='img' height='200' image={props.img} alt='icon' />
        <CardContent>
          <Typography gutterBottom variant='h5' component='div'>
            {props.name}
          </Typography>

          <Typography variant='body2' color='text.secondary'>
            {props.description}
          </Typography>

          <Typography style={{}}>TK. {props.price}</Typography>
        </CardContent>
      </Card>
    </div>
  );
};

export default ItemCard;
```

[Please see this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eUcxy.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a `min-height` css property in your description `Typography` component like below (make sure the height is enough for fitting two lines. In case you have longer than two lines of description you can add the ellipsis css properties like [in this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73391405/5376404)):

```
<Typography variant='body2' color='text.secondary' sx={{minHeight: "30px"}}>
  {props.description}
</Typography>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this!

```
<CardActions>
  <Typography style={{}}>TK. {props.price}</Typography>
</CardActions>
```

Comment: I have tried it but it's still the same unfortunately. The price of the third card is not aligning with the other cards. The only possible solution I found was to make 2 line description text of the third card.